# Is there a typing hint in Python for a generic class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have some legacy code that I inherited that creates a class on the fly within a method.  The type returned is just <class 'module'>.  How do I type hint this?

I know I can use `Any`, but I was hoping for something a bit more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the type is `<class 'module'>` that means it returns **modules**. The annotation for that is the [`types.ModuleType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.ModuleType). And it is not generic.

Comment: Thank you, this will do! I must have missed this.  Sometime parsing legacy code makes your head spin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type).
It's a generic, and you have to provide it with the base class of the class you create on the flight.
If you don't know the base class, you can do `Type[Any]`.

```
def create_class() -> Type[Any]:
    return type("Foo", tuple(), {})
```